# SignalR in react-native weird thing happens

Tags: reactjs, .net, react-native, signalr

We have a working application in ReactJS and there is a part which is a real time chat between different users. In reactJs we used @microsoft/signalR and everything works fine. This is the block of code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ConnectionId = "e48950002479" // user.token;
    const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://none_of_your_business/chatHub', {
        accessTokenFactory: () => ConnectionId
      }) //replace with the URL of your SignalR hub
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
      .build();

    setConnection(newConnection);
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (connection) {
      connection
        .start()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("SignalR Connected!");

          connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message) => {
            console.log("Received message:", message);
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(`SignalR Connection error: ${error}`));
    }
  }, [connection]);

  const sendMessage = async () => {


    await connection.invoke('SendMessage', "1626659a57c6", "Heyo", "1626659a57c6");
  };
```

however when I copied the same code for react-native (with the same library), the thing does not send the ConnectionId variable. It is really weird because it works flawless in reactJS but not in react-native. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by changing:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ConnectionId = "e48950002479" // user.token;
    const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://none_of_your_business/chatHub?access_token=' + ConnectionId) //replace with the URL of your SignalR hub
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
      .build();

    setConnection(newConnection);
  }, [])
```